# TypeError with String indices using integers with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code for a programming problem in a CS course that involves tokenizing a string by its opening and closing parentheses.

```
def expand(S):
        if "(" in S:
            open, close = parentheses_pair(S)
            open = int(int(open) + int(1))
            samp = S[open, close]
            currstr = samp
            innerstr = ""
            if "(" in samp:
                open, close = parentheses_pair(S)
                currstr = samp[:open]
                innerstr = samp[open, close+1]
                innerstr = expand(innerstr)
            output = ""
            for i in range(1, len(currstr), 2):
                letter = currstr[i-1]
                number = currstr[i]
                output += letter*number
            output += innerstr
            sorted_out = sorted(output)
            output = "".join(sorted_out)
            return output
        else:
            return ""
def parentheses_pair(S):
        counter = 0
        openpar = S.find("(")
        currind = S.find("(")
        found = False
        while not found:
                if S[currind] == "(":
                        counter += 1
                elif S[currind] == ")":
                        if counter == 1:
                                found = True
                                break
                        else:
                                counter -= 1
                currind += 1
        return int(openpar), int(currind)
```

When I used `type` on both `open` and `close`, `<class 'int'>` was returned by the terminal so I really don't know why it won't accept the variables as the string indices on `samp = S[open, close]`.

Comment: What input did you give?

Comment: `S[open, close]` is not valid. Try it with a simple string: `S = "abcdef"` ... `S[1, 3]` <- that's an error even with integers. Maybe you want `S[open:close]`? When you get errors like this, you should break it down to the simplest thing that causes the error and figure that out.

Comment: What a careless mistake. I didn't even realize I used a comma. Thanks for pointing that out. I did in fact want to use `S[open:close]`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips. For debugging help in the future, please make a [mre], which will help you isolate the problem, and therefore hopefully make it more obvious.

Comment: BTW, your indentation is inconsistent - sometimes 4, sometimes 8. You'll want to be more careful, since that's an easy way to cause bugs.

Comment: `open` is also a python built-in function, so you are shadowing a python function. This is generally not a good practice. Try to avoid that and use other names.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.